# How to Align center in IONIC

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, ionic-framework

I am trying to align my Row items in center but actually its not going anywhere i am using Bootstrap CSS and ionic CSS i tried with both of them Can anyone check and tell me where i Am doing wrong.

HTML CODE ->

```
<div class="bar bar-header">
  <div class="tabs-striped tabs-color-assertive">
    <div class="row">
  <a class="tab-item col col-sm-6" data-ink-color="#ef473a" data-ink-opacity=".35" ng-click="activeMap()" ng-class="{'active': !isActive}" > <i class="icon ion-map"></i></a>
  <a class="tab-item col col-sm-6" data-ink-color="#ef473a" data-ink-opacity=".35"  ng-click="activeList()" ng-class="{'active': isActive}" > <i class="icon ion-ios-list-outline"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I actually want to make it responsive and that's why escaping from **OWN CSS**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6q3BI.png

Comment: can you post a screenshot or a plunker demo.. so that we can resolve your problem easy

Comment: `text-align:center` should work perfectly for the class `bar`?

Answer (score 0):

to center anything in css you must use a specific width in main div then center inside divs with margin like this example:

```
<div class='main-div'>

 <div class='inside-div'>
  test
 </div>

</div>
```

and css look like :

```
.main-div{width:100%;}

.inside-div{width:50%;margin:0 auto; //or margin-right:25%; margin-left:25%;}
```

( 100 - inside-div width ) / 2 = margin left or  right %

Comment: yup thanks its working but let me check it out I will appreciate you